# Possible LINQ query, Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two main tables Task and Person. There is also a linking table called Assign.

A Task can have many Person records linked via the Assign table.

I have a Create form which is working well, with a multiple select list where i can add multiple people to the Assign table at once for any Session.

I want the values of my selectlist to be filtered to NOT include records from the Person Table that already exist in the Assign table with based on the Task id (passed on the create request URL string).

```
    public IActionResult Create(int task)
    {
    ViewData["PersonId"] = new SelectList(_context.Person, "PersonId", "PersonName");
    ViewData["TaskId"] = new SelectList(_context.Task, "TaskId", "TaskName", task);


    return View();

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the models for Person, Task, and Assign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited

```
ViewData["PersonId"] = new SelectList(_context.Person.Where(a=>a.Assign.Any(b=>b.TaskId == task), "PersonId", "PersonName");
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it didn't solve it, but did get me thinking. The problem with your solution was that a=>a.Assign does not include a reference to TaskId which is odd (because i think it does)

Comment: In case if you still need this `ViewData["PersonId"] = new SelectList(_context.Person.Where(a=>a.Assign.Any(b=>b.TaskId == task), "PersonId", "PersonName");`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a new VAR for all the items i want to remove, then queried against them:

```
var query = from a in _context.Assign.where (a.Task == task) select a.PersonId;

        ViewData["PersonId"] = new SelectList(_context.Person.Where(x => !query.Contains(x.PersonId)).ToList(), "PersonId", "Fullname");
```